# How to create Virtual Network in Azure using GoLang API?

Tags: azure, go, azure-virtual-network

Currently I am trying to create Virtual Network using the GoLang code:

```
client := network.NewVirtualNetworksClient(subscriptionID)
var parameters network.VirtualNetwork
c := make(<-chan struct{})

c1, err := client.CreateOrUpdate(resourceGroupName, virtualNetworkName, parameters, c)

utils.Info.Println(err.Error())
utils.Info.Println(c1)
```

But the code isn't working fine. It throws the following exception:

Failure sending request: StatusCode=401 -- Original Error: Long running operation terminated with status 'Failed': Code="AuthenticationFailed" Message="Authentication failed. The 'Authorization' header is missing."

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There is some good documentation in general for using Azure authentication that you can find here: [azure-sdk-for-node/Documentation/Authentication](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/blob/master/Documentation/Authentication.md)

While there isn't an example for Virtual Networks specifically yet, you can find [Azure SDK for Go samples here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=&type=&language=go).

For Go in particular, you can update a Client to use an authentication token, so your code would look something like this:

```
c := make(chan struct{})
authConfig, err0 := azure.PublicCloud.OAuthConfigForTenant(<yourTenantID>)
token, err1 := azure.NewServicePrincipalToken(
                  *authConfig,
                  <yourClientID>,
                  <yourClientSecret>,
                  azure.PublicCloud.ResourceManagerEndpoint) 

client := network.NewVirtualNetworkClient(subscriptionID)
client.Authorizer = token

var parameters network.VirtualNetwork
c1, err2 := client.CreateOrUpdate(resourceGroupName, virtualNetworkName, parameters, c)
```

Comment: Thanks @MarStr. When I as working on this, Azure API for Golang was highly unstable. I used REST API instead. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you use [GoLang SDK for Azure](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/) ? The reason of the error is that when you make a request, it does not have the Authorization header. Authorization header is the JSON Web Token that you can obtain from Azure Active Directory

1) Take a look at the request in the Fiddler and see if your request is aligned [with the rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163650.aspx).

2) Go with the tutorials about how to get the token ([1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790557.aspx) and [2](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal/#get-access-token-in-code)).

Comment: I'm getting error while setting the header. Can you please share an example of setting header?

Comment: In GoLang - no, sorry :-)  What error? for setting the header, you should follow the notation - request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Bearer " + token); "Authorization: Bearer mF_9.B5f-4.1JqM". That token should be received from backend (see GetAcessToken method in the third link i provided).

Comment: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=404 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: error response cannot be parsed: "" error

Comment: Ugh... Difficult to say. Can you take a Fiddler session for that request? It looks like the request is malformed and can't even find the server.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I really appreciate your response.

Comment: Add Fiddler session here - i would try to help.